# Better way to call rust function in other file within the same directory?

Tags: rust

I have a directory like this:

```
.
├── a.rs
├── b.rs
└── main.rs
```

main.rs:

```
mod a;
use a::a;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    a();
}
```

a.rs:

```
mod b;
use b::b;

pub fn a() {
    b();
}
```

b.rs:

```
pub fn b() {
    println!("b");
}
```

rustc complaints in a.rs about

```
file not found for module `b`

help: to create the module `b`, create file "src/a/b.rs" or "src/a/b/mod.rs"rustc(E0583)
```

If I put `mod b;` in main.rs, and replace `mod b;` with `use crate::b::b;` in a.rs, everything works well.

My question is: do I have to put every `mod xxx;` in the file where `main()` locates? I just want to call functions in the same-level rs files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put `mod b;` in `a.rs`, `b` will be considered as a submodule of module `a`. So, as suggested by `rustc`, it should be either in "src/a/b/mod.rs" or "src/a/b.rs". And when you put it instead in `main.rs`, it means that this module in located at the `crate` root, reason why it works without any problem because `rustc` looks for the file in the same directory as `main.rs`("src") and find it.

So, you don't have to put every `mod xxx` where main is located. If you creating an hierarchy (I mean `modules` and `submodules` and so on), you should respect the directory architecture and put `mod xxx`, only in the parent module, if any. You declare `mod xxx` in your main file for top level modules only.

You can see more explanation in the [book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-00-managing-growing-projects-with-packages-crates-and-modules.html) :).

Comment: Does it mean the directory where main.rs locates is also treated as a mod?

Comment: Yes, `main.rs` is a crate root, meaning that, `rustc` start with processing it first. It's the same for the `lib.rs` file when you developing a library. They form the module named `crate` located at the root of your code. That's why you can use `crate::some_mod` to reference other modules.